# How to mysql_real_escape_string a zero

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm trying to input a phone number from a html form to my MySQL database with `mysql_real_escape_string`. The number is 0123456789, but it's written as 23456789 in my database. Does anyone know how to insert that zero along with the other numbers in my database, or if there is any way to break the form value in to characters then input them one by one into my MySQL db?

Here's my code that doesn't input the zero:

```
<?php
$Phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` (`phone`) VALUES ('{$Phone}')");
?>
```

Comment: Change the column datatype to varchar; or apply a formatter when yo display the value

Comment: What is the `type` of your `phone` column? It should be `varchar` that would allow the 0 in front. If its a numeric type, it will remove the 0

Comment: Phone numbers are not numbers.

Comment: My SQL database is currently int(11), guess I must change it to varchar

Comment: @SLaks makes a very important point: Phone numbers, SSNs, PINs, Zip codes, and lots of other similar data points.... None of these should be stored as numeric values. **Because they're not numbers!!!!** Yes, they're a sequence of digits, but they're not numbers. Don't treat them as such. (I get constantly annoyed by data files with Zip codes where leading zeros have been trimmed off because of this mistake)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That has nothing to do with escaping. You need to store the value as a string, not an integer, if you want to maintain leading zeros.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I just need to change my database structure from int(11) to varchar(225)

Comment: I have never heard of a phone number that's 255 digits long.

Comment: You don't really need varchar(225), surely varchar(11) would be enough for 11 digits

Comment: Even '0118 999 881 999 119 725 3' isn't that long.

Comment: @Chong just keep it 255, it wont hurt anyone

Comment: The international recommendation from ITU is at least 15 digits; having it about 20..30 (for counting for spaces, (), / etc.) will probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should change data type to varchar(10) and if you will want later to process it as number just parse it from string. Number 01xxx doesn't exist in databases.

Answer (score -3):

PHP is loosely typed.  Assuming the phone field is being stored as a VARCHAR / CHAR and not a numeric datatype, the escape string is doing what it should.  PHP will see the data in the $_POST variable as an integer, and will truncate the 0 at the front before passing it to the mysql_real_escape_string() function.  If you modify the argument to `( '' . $_POST['phone'] )`, it will cast to a string and work as intended.

```
<?php 
    $phone = mysql_real_escape_string( '' . $_POST['phone'] );
```

Comment: PHP will do no such thing. It only type casts to a number if the value is involved in a numeric operation, which is not the case here. Your own logic is not even internally consistent. If PHP would do such a thing, it'd have already done it before passing the value into the function, so "casting it to a string" at that point would already be too late.

Comment: It's not acceptable to post requests for clarification as answers on this site. This is not a forum, and there are strict rules on what kind of content you can submit here. If you no longer feel your answer is relevant, you can simply delete it.